# How can I use fragment caching to exclude certain plugins from being cached?

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, cache

I'm using the popular W3TC to optimize load times. The website that I run is dynamic and has login widgets as well as status indicators for game servers. The widgets are not hard-coded into the template file, so I don't see how I could do this manually. I have tried using wildcard names in the W3TC settings exclude all php files associated with the plugin,

> xenword-.*.php

This doesn't seem to work either.

How else can I exclude certain plugins using fragment caching so that they don't get cached?